# How to select radlistview item programmatically

Tags: nativescript

- I'm navigating to a new page on click of a floating action button.
- This FAB will be visible only when an item of radlistview is
  selected.
- now after going to new page when I came back by
  `frameModule.topmost().goBack();`
- the item was not selected anymore, but the fab are still showing.

So, I need a way to select item when I came back to same page.

***points to help***
when I came back I have the selected data of rad list view.

```
exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = CreateViewModel;

    if (CreateViewModel.selected_dataItem)
        console.log("present");
    else
        console.log("absent");
}
```

to show and hide fab

```
itemSelecting: function(args) {

            viewModel.selected_dataItem = args.view.bindingContext;
            this.show_floating_action = "visible";

        },

        itemDeselecting: function(args) {

            viewModel.selected_dataItem = "";
            this.show_floating_action = "collapsed";

        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `selectItemAt`. just do as follow

```
pageLoaded function:-

if (vm.selected_dataItem) {
        var radlistview = args.object.getViewById("radlistview"); // read id
        radlistview.selectItemAt(CreateViewModel.selected_dataItem_index); // select it
    }
```

beware of error `bindingContext of undefined` add below lines of code.

```
itemSelecting: function(args) {

*** add this line to your code 
if (args.view) {
          viewModel.selected_dataItem_index = args.index; 
***

          viewModel.selected_dataItem = args.view.bindingContext;
          this.show_floating_action = "visible";
      }
}
```